# How to save a local streaming video of firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I am trying to share screen. I have actually used the video tag of html to stream video and then I am using the play option of this video. Now I want to save the video in my computer. How will I achieve it. For reference, below is the code:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

// Test browser support
window.navigator = window.navigator || {};
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         null;

if (navigator.getUserMedia === null) {
    // document.getElementById('gum-unsupported').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById('videorecorderplay-button-recorder').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    document.getElementById('videorecorderstop-button-recorder').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
    // Opera <= 12.16 accepts the direct stream.
    // More on this here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/playing-with-html5-video-and-getusermedia-support/
    var createSrc = window.URL ? window.URL.createObjectURL : function (stream) { return stream; };

    // Opera <= 12.16 support video only.
    var audioContext = window.AudioContext ||
                       window.webkitAudioContext ||
                       null;
    if (audioContext === null) {
        document.getElementById('gum-partially-supported').classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    //document.getElementById('videorecorderplay-button-recorder').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var constraints = {}
    constraints = {
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                minWidth: 1280,
                minHeight: 720,
                minFrameRate: 30
            },
            optional: [
              { minFrameRate: 60 }
            ],
            mediaSource: "screen"
        },        

    };
    // Capture user's audio and video source

    navigator.mozGetUserMedia(constraints, function(stream) {
        console.log("Received local stream");
        videoStream = stream;
        video.src = createSrc(stream);
        video.play();
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
    });        

}
```

Once I am calling the video.play(), my screen sharing start. Now I want to save it. How will I do this.